# Why cannot pi value 22/7(3.14..) be written in $p/q$ form?

Tags: pi

Since a rational number e.g 1/4 or -1/4  can be written in form of $p/q$, why cannot we write irrational $pi$ value which is also $22/7$ ,in form of p/q?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational

Comment: $\pi$ isn't really $\frac {22}7$, that's just an approximation.  $\pi= 3.14159265358979\cdots$ while $\frac {22}7=3.\overline {142857}$

Comment: I have not calculated 22/7 but it it non terminating recurring?

Comment: If you believe that $\pi$ is $\frac{22}{7}$ then why not take $p=22$ and $q=7$?

Comment: The reason is that pi is classified as an irrational number. Simply put, it has non ending sequence of dissimilar digits after the decimal point and does not even get closer to a specific rational value. Only Rational numbers can be written as a/b. See https://www.mathsisfun.com/irrational-numbers.html

Comment: Ok so it is non terminating and non recurring digits after decimal point  which makes it irrational.

Answer (score 0):

“why cannot we write irrational pi value which is also 22/7...”

It is true that $\pi$ is irrational but then this implies that $\pi$ cannot be rational and hence cannot be written as a fraction of two integers such as $\frac{22}{7}.$

For a wonderful proof (techniques of elementary calculus used here), see https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788